# How do slide, push and pull works for huge and gargantuan enemies?

Tags: dnd-4e

Basically, can a medium monk slide or push or pull a huge or gargantuan enemy?

Can any character (the example with my party was a monk) move (slide, push or pull) a bigger creature than him? in 3.5e you could only move a creature one size bigger than you, but this rule is not specified in 4e.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Unless the power says otherwise, yes.***

Most powers do not make an exception based on creature size. However, a few do. The Fighter's Tide of Iron does (up to one size category larger than the PC). The always available Bull Rush has the same exception.

There is no rule in 4e related to size categories with respect to forced movement. If the power says slide, you slide; push, you push. Regardless to the size of the creature. If there are restrictions on who you can force to move, the power will lay them out.